# How to create a PHP date like 2013-09-21T18:56:19+00:00?

Tags: php, datetime

How to create a PHP date format like this `2013-09-21T18:56:19+00:00`? Can anyone expalain why we use this format and why use `T` between `2013-09-21` and `18:56:19+00:00`.

Example: I need like this.

```
date('Y-m-d'); // 2013-12-12
```

same way how to generate `2013-09-21T18:56:19+00:00` and which format and function use for this purpose.

Comment: [`date('c');`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use date('c') which outputs [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, this has been added from PHP 5.

```
echo date('c');

//will return
2014-01-14T10:04:38+00:00
```

For more info read the [PHP Date Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
date( 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP' )
```

Result:

2014-01-14T03:05:34-07:00

Here is an Generator for different php date() formats: http://www.b2ben.com/php/phpdate.php

Comment: This works for versions under `PHP5`, but if you have `PHP5+`, then use the `date('c');` instead.

Comment: What's the meaning of T